# django unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, django, indentation

I have noticed that whenever I use redirect statement, I get an error

```
unindent does not match any outer indentation level (views.py, line 16)
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. As soon as I remove redirect code and put render_to_response I am able to see the response. What am I doing wrong?

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/priyank/dev/projects/asome/asom/usr/views.py in dashboard

def dashboard(request):    
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/login/?next=%s' % request.path)
    else:
        user = request.user
        user_orders = Order.objects.filter(user=user.user_id)    
        return render_to_response('views/usr/dashboard.html',{'my_orders':user_orders})
```

After checking out similar questions on this site
I tried this command also.

```
python -m tabnanny views.py
```

But it didnt give any errors.

Here is my file.

```
from django.shortcuts  import render_to_response,redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout
import helper as uhelper
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from business.models import BusinessUser
from utils.core_classes import UserContext
import utils.constants as constants
from order.models import Order

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_to_response('views/usr/register.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        params = request.POST
        user = User.objects.create_user(params['email'], params['email'], params['password'])
        user.save()
        return authenticate(request)

def login(request):
    return render_to_response('views/usr/login.html')

def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/');

def dashboard(request):    
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/login/?next=%s' % request.path)
    else:
        user = request.user
        user_orders = Order.objects.filter(user=user.user_id)    
        return render_to_response('views/usr/dashboard.html',{'my_orders':user_orders})

def profile(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_to_response('views/usr/profile.html')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        return render_to_response('views/usr/profile.html')

def authenticate(request):
    user_dict = request.POST
    user = User()
    user = uhelper.authenticate_user(user_dict['email'], user_dict['password'])
    if user != None:
        return redirect('/usr/dashboard')
```

Here is a traceback

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                        response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/priyank/dev/projects/stuffednow/stuffed/usr/views.py in dashboard
        return redirect('/login/?next=%s' % request.path) ...
▶ Local vars
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.2-py2.7.egg/django/shortcuts/__init__.py in redirect
        return redirect_class(urlresolvers.reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs))
```

Comment: Perhaps you have tabs and spaces mixed in your indentation?  Also, what is line 16 in your `views.py`?

Comment: I dont think I have. For a quick test i created another def and added just redirect piece. Whenever I add that I start getting above error.

Comment: Post the first 20 lines.

Comment: you don't think, but probably you are... reindent everything (remove all white spaces, starting from the top of your file. and if you want to take the hassle, do it line by line, only using tabs or return to send some code to a new auto-indented line, if your editor supports it)

Comment: added file for reference.

Comment: Assuming I have white spaces and tabs mixed, why would the code only break when I add redirect code ?

Comment: first off, where is the redirect code ? Also, post the full trace back. did you ever mess with or refer to django/shortcuts/__init__.py ?

Comment: i messed up with the answer. anyway: is that semicolon intended or a typo? :)

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo you can ignore semicolon. I was checking if putting semicolon makes any difference.

Comment: @Amyth All statements like "return redirect('/')". I have not modified __init__.py

Comment: Are you copy and pasting the return redirect('/')? Or tabbing and actually writing it?

Comment: I tried writing and copy-pasting both. There are no tabs. Verified by doing "cat -vet filename"

Comment: @Amyth I will paste full stacktrace later in the evening as I dont have my access to that computer right now.

Comment: It might be something with the string formatting inside redirect(). Have you tried redirecting to home or something like redirect(reverse('home')), or try variations for the string: ('/login/?next=%s' % (request.path)), or ('/login/?next=' + request.path)

Comment: Yes I tried redirecting to different website, different url.

Answer (score -1):

There is the problem:

```
def logout_user(request):
logout(request)
return redirect('/');
```

Delete the ";" at end of code